# New raspberry pi model a+ trouble

Tags: raspberry-pi, hdmi

I have just got the new Raspberry Pi model a+ and was very excited. Removed the old model a, and replaced it with the new model a+'s 26 compatible pins. I started fine, and I can see it runs the code as it should. However, I have already run into two problems.

1. The HDMI port does not show anything on the screen anymore. This has never been an issue before. I use the LINDY hdmi to vga adaptor.
2. I was very excited to see how much the powerconsumption would decrease. But was very disapointed to see the powerconsumption actually increased by 50%, whitch was a bit of a blow.

I have just replaced the old model a with the new model a+ and copied a raspian image to a 16gb micro sd. I know there is not a lot of experence yet on the subject, but maybe some of you also will have simular problemems?

Best Regards Allan

Comment: Try running a sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade on another Pi. There might be some necessary software updates required for the A+. There *shouldn't* be, but it's a good place to start

Comment: Hi, you are right. Found out yestoday that the Raspbian OS just needed an upgrade

Comment: Guess I better put that as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try running a

sudo apt-get update

and

sudo apt-get upgrade

on another Pi with the same SD card inserted. There might be some necessary software updates required for the A+.